# ASP.NET MVC validation & Jquery password strength for bootstrap

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I want to design a user registration page. In this page there will be a password input. That password input uses [JQuery password strength meter](https://plugins.jquery.com/pwstrength-bootstrap/) to show how the password is strong. And i want to use asp.net validation to show error when the password is not strong enough. But i dont know how to do that.

JQuery password strength meter pushes a string to a span that indicates how the password is strong (Eg: weak, normal, strong )

How can i show error when password is not strong enough using asp.net mvc validation?

Comment: I don't think you will be able to use built in asp.net validation to accomplish this as this isn't something that .net natively validates. However you can easily write some of your own javascript to apply the .net validation error styles / message that would mimic built in validation.

Comment: You will probably have to add a custom rule that the plugin allows. The rule will return a score. Then you can use that score with a plugin like jquery validate.